# update combobox from another form in c#

Tags: c#

I want to update combobox of the main form from another form
this is my main form combobox update code which is in the form_load

```
public void main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter db = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from category", con);
        ds_cmbGroup.Clear();
        cmbGroup.DataSource = null;
        db.Fill(ds_cmbGroup, "t1");
        cmbGroup.DisplayMember = "catname";
        cmbGroup.ValueMember = "catcode";
        cmbGroup.DataSource = ds_cmbGroup.Tables["t1"];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

as I call this method in its own form it runs correctly. this is the code to call it:

```
main_Load(this, null);
```

but when I call it from another form, (though the dataset updates with no problem) it doesn't change the combobox(cmbGroup) content
this is the code to load main_Load method from second form:

```
main Main = new main();
Main.main_Load(this, null);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: when cooking spaghetti avoid starch.

Comment: can you change your variable names..try something like `main frmMain` hard to keep straight lol also show all relevant code.. especially the `form` or `Method` where you are creating the `Instance` of the other form..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you dont reference the current instance of main form but you create a new instace, on second form try:

```
 Main  obj = (Main)Application.OpenForms["Main"];
```

and then use `obj` to refer to `main Form`