# How to update a ComboBox from a window when closing another window?

Tags: c#, winforms

First of all, I want to apologize for:

- The software is in Portuguese.
- The software is ugly as hell. It is for a school project and we decided to focus more on the funcionality than the design (I know, it's wrong, but we had to choose...)
- I read [update combobox from another form in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15768012) but I didn't understand what happened.

That said, let's go to the issue.

I have this window:

[image: pretty window]

If I click the button marked in red:

[image: look the red thing]

This will open:

[image: the other window]

This is supposed to be a software for a market. The first window is responsible to order more thing to the inventory. The second window is responsible to add a supplier into the system.

The combobox shows all the suppliers on the system. I want when I finish adding a supplier on the second window after I clicked on the button highlighted with the red rectangle, the combobox will update automatically with the new data.

I used a "Update" button with this code:

```
this.tb_FornecedorTableAdapter.Fill(this.tccDataSet.tb_Fornecedor);
```

It worked, but I tried to use on `FormClosing`, `FormClosed` and `Deactivate` events on the other windows and it didn't work at all (I modified the "this" on the code to a lot of this and it didn't help me). Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ComboBox is updated with the data from SQL Server then you can try this:

```
// When button Adicionar is clicked
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(Form formAdd = new Form()) // This is the Gerenciar Fornecedor form
    {
        formAdd.ShowDialog(this); // Show the form. The next statement will not be executed until formAdd is closed
        // Put the your code to update the ComboBox items here
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm testing all the suggestions but your code worked so far. thanks. :D

Comment: @athosbr99 - using `formAdd` this way causes a memory leak, which will be noticeable if it is shown many times during normal use. Better to wrap it inside a `using` clause like `using (var formAdd = new FormAdd()) { ...}`. See note on MSDN about calling `Dispose()` after [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In the first window declare a public methord:

```
public void RefreshCombo()
{
this.tb_FornecedorTableAdapter.Fill(this.tccDataSet.tb_Fornecedor);
}
```

Then in the first window add button click event

```
WindowB window=new WindowB(this);
WindowB.Show();
```

Then in the child window add a ctor method:

```
private WindowA windowParent;

public WindowB(WindowA parent)
{
InitializeComponent();
this.windowParent=parent;     
}
```

In WindowB FormClosing Event

```
this.windowParent.RefreshCombo()
```

Comment: your third piece of code, could you explain what it does? i wasn't able to understand

Comment: store a WindowA instance,so you can use the instance in WindowB convenient.Try this code and debug, and you will understand.

Comment: sorry,i can't open the picture.Is there a Exception?

Comment: no, this appears instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx. is that expected? you typed "parent" not "Parent" so i'm thinking that you are referring to the variable not the class

Comment: Yes,you are right,I want to use the variable.Try this.windowParent.RefreshCombo()

Comment: i got a NullReferenceException on the FormClosing event

Comment: I can't use this editor to show a section of code in correct format.Please look at my answer Step3.

Comment: I forgot something on the code and I managed to get it working. thanks. :D

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in this case is to add a property on the child form to store the combo box value and populate it when the combo box value changes. Also, create a method on the child form that will be called from the parent form. It will show the child form and return the combo box value.

```
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string _comboValue { get; set; }

    public string ShowAndGetComboValue()
    {
        this.ShowDialog();

        return _comboValue;
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _comboValue = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

On the parent form, you can then display the child form this way:

```
ChildForm form = new ChildForm();
string comboValue = form.ShowAndGetComboValue();
```

Comment: i think i got your logic, but what kind of stuff would be stored on "_combovalue"? and the ShowAndGetComboValue() would be created on the second window?

Comment: You can see how `_combovalue` is used. Yes, you're right, `ShowAndGetComboValue()` is set in the 2nd window.

Comment: "comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "1", "2", "3" });"

AddRange? I get the data from a SQL Server... so this would be a problem?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was for my testing. I removed it from the code above.

Comment: the first block of code is going all to the 2nd window? the "private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)" wouldn't work there because the combobox is on the 1st screen... i got it wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I got it the other way... Anyway, you can return the info from the second window using this pattern.